# How to disable unique constraint on composite key in many-to-many relationship?

Tags: sequelize.js

When 2 models are associated in a many-to-many relation in Sequelize through a junction table, a composite key is created out of the 2 foreign keys from the 2 models.
In the sequelize documentation found here: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/advanced-many-to-many.html
it says that it's possible to force the table to have a ID privateKey.

A and C are 2 models in a many-to-many relation. The junction table/model is B.
Models A and C definition is irrelevant for this example.

```
//Defining the junction table B with the private key ID
sequelize.define('B', {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
    allowNull: false
  }
}, { timestamps: false });

A.belongsToMany(Profile, { through: B });
C.belongsToMany(User, { through: B });
```

Even when adding my ID private key to that table, a unique constraint of those 2 foreign keys still exists. How do I disable that constraint?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

****ANSWER FOUND****

To anyone browsing the web for the answer, its simple, you have to pass the `unique: false` option in on the **through** model.

```
A.belongsToMany(Profile, { through: { model: B, unique: false}});
C.belongsToMany(User, { through:  { model: B, unique: false}});
```

Comment: Can I also use custom unique columns? Lets say I want to have a third column which has no relationship to another table but should be part of uniqueness?

Comment: @rasenkantenstein it's quite easy as you just need to define a standard 'unique' index with your combination column arrays in your through model.